# Spreads in the pages panel are stuck together

Tags: adobe-indesign

When duplicating a spread, the new pages are stuck on the right side of the previous spread. In the pages panel, this looks like a four-page spread. can't seem to split them apart.

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with these 2 options in the Pages panel: Allow document pages to shuffle / Allow selected spreads to shuffle. These are probably turned 'on' for your document which will result in this behaviour. More info on this can be googled.

[image: allow pages to shuffle]